# Does it make sense to split big DB2 tables into multiple tables to improve the performance?

Tags: database, performance, db2, database-performance, database-partitioning

We are currently having an OLTP application storing information in a DB2 database.
The information regarding the declarations is stored in multiple DB2 tables and some of the tables are really huge (260 million records).

If we want to improve the performance would it make sense to duplicate each of those tables used to store the declaration info.  So instead of having a single table DECLARATION, we now have 2 tables DECLARATION_A and DECLARATION_B.  The idea is to store the information related to Declarations with type A in the DECLARATION_A table and declarations with type B in the DECLARATION_B table.

1. So will this kind of split, improve the performance of those business processes that are writing to and reading from those Declaration tables ?
2. Or even more specifically : will this kind of split also assure that business process A that is reading/updating/creating records for Declarations with type A *is less impacted* by concurrent business process B that is reading/updated/creating records for Declarations with type B ?

Comment: A clear "it depends" is the answer. With the information provided it can not be decided. Note that partitioning might be an option as separating the tables might have a negative impact also.

Comment: Your way to improve performance is by having a duplicate table duplicate programs duplicate everything.  You'll have to buy a lot of cheap programmers.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher thanks for the response.  My understanding is that _DB2 table partitioning_ is based on dividing the table data based on values in one or more columns.  This doesn't seem an option for us as the value to divide on is not in the big table but is located in the parent table.  You have said it depends, then it indicates that in some cases it improves the performance.  Can you share the factors that would result in better performance when using splitted tables knowing that we are using "cursor stability" as isolation level ?

Comment: @JanVdA separating is an option only if the data has the same structure but is independend in all other aspects. If you need to handle the data as a whole it is not the right way. On the other hand if you think of dividing the tables you will change the model anyway so you could also add the column (from the parent table) in order to get an approriate column to partition over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I don't believe that splitting the table would improve your performance and I will try, at a high level explain why. In case you split the table into `A` and `B`, then you have to route updates to one and reads to the other. Even if reads are accelerated by avoiding concurrent reads (let's assume that you currently use a pessimistic locking protocol), then periodically you need to make sure that updates are propagated to the read table (e.g., `B`) from the update table (e.g., `A`). The former operation will incur additional overhead, thus, in the end I don't expect your performance to improve.

In addition, DBMSs are designed in a way to avoid conflicts as much as possible among different memory pages. In other words, if your latest transaction is updating page `X`, then a read transaction will be affected until the lock on page `X` is released. Depending on your workload, page `X` will be the last page (in an append-only workload), or multiple pages in memory (in a random update pattern).

In conclusion, I think you need to provide the locking mechanism that your database is using, and the operation profile (i.e., percentage of SELECT/INSERT/DELETE/UPDATEs) of your application.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Note that in our case there is no need to propagate any updates from table DECLARATION_A to table DECLARATION_B or vice versa.  FYI if type of declaration = A then it will be stored in table DECLARATION_A, and if type of declaration = B it will be stored in table DECLARATION_B.

We are using the default DB2 isolation level which is **cursor stability**

Comment: Your answer is confusing me: you claim an OLTP workload but then you don't have updates? 

Regardless, if you don't have updates, then your workload ends up being dependent on the raw scan performance (i.e., OLAP). In this case, you can divide the two tables based on the type of the declaration, or you could store them in the same table and index them based on the Declaration type to improve performance. As far as database consistency is concerned, it's safer to have all data types in the same table and not duplicate relations based on attribute value (i.e., maintain BCNF form).

Comment: Also, you have received a number of answers that provide actionable insights for your situation. Therefore, please up-vote the ones that were actually helpful and mark one of them as an actual answer. Be kind to the community please :-)

Comment: thanks for the response - regarding the confusion about "updates".  I didn't mean that there won't be any updates in tables DECLARATION_A and DECLARATION_B.  What I meant was that there is no ¨*propagation of the updates* from one table (what you called the read table in your answer) to the other table.  So I am not sure if you understood my question.

Comment: I see. Well, you can improve the performance by indexing the table based on the declaration type and you will get the same (if not better performance) with having two different tables. With the index on the declaration type your transaction logic will be more sound to reason against. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, with your isolation level set to __cursor__ stability, you might get stale data in your transaction logic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If it is an OLTP application, it means short transactions with record-level, index-based access. Is using the same hardware with two databases fighting for the same resources a good idea?

If it is a messy OLTP-like system with not-sure-what-we-are-doing implementation, revisiting the architecture and programs and eventually splitting the data by purpose/business app might be good.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  
Note that I didn't mean 2 databases, but I meant to duplicate the tables in the database.  E.g. instead of table DECLARATION, we will now have 2 tables: DECLARATION_A and DECLARATION_B which have exactly the same set of columns.
Note also that the declarations with type = A and declarations with type = B have most fields in common therefore they are currently stored in the same DECLARATION table.